# Fill some columns of a data table with those of anoter data table?

Tags: merge, datatable

I have two data tables: DT1, which has numerical values and DT2, which has NAs.
They have some column names in common.

I want the columns of DT1 to fill the corresponding columns in DT2.

Note that I want to keep the remaining columns in DT2.

First, I buit `DT1` and `DT2`.

```
G <- c("C", "H1", "H2", "P", "D", "I")  
C <- c(0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0, 0) 
H1 <- c(0, 0, 0.2, 0.8, 0, 0) 
H2 <- c(0, 0.1, 0, 0.9, 0, 0) 
P <- rep(NA, 6) 
DT1 <- data.table(G, C, H1, H2, P)

G <- c("C", "H", "P", "D", "I")  
C <- rep(NA, 5)
H <- rep(NA, 5) 
P <- rep(NA, 5) 
DT2 <- data.table(G, C, H, P)
```

Next, I took a subset of `DT2` in which the row and column labelled `H` are absent.
Respectively, I took a subset of `DT1` without `H1` and `H2`.

```
DT1[G != "H1" & G != "H2", .SD, .SDcols =! c("H1", "H2")]
DT2[G != "H", .SD, .SDcols =! "H"]
```

When I try to merge them using

```
DT2[G != "H", .SD, .SDcols =! "H"] <- DT1[G != "H1" & G != "H2", .SD, .SDcols =! c("H1", "H2")]
```

I expect DT2 to be

```
   G C  H  P
1: C 0 NA NA
2: H 0 NA NA
3: P 0 NA NA
4: D 0 NA NA
5: I 0 NA NA
```

Instead, I get this error

```
Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, G != "H", .SD, .SDcols = !"H",  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = !"H")
```

Bonus: Is there a more concise/efficient way to take a subset of data tables' based on rows and columns names?

Thank you!